# Run PHP with attributes

Tags: php, exec

I wont to run an exe from users harddrive with attributes directly from my php file.

My php file reads xml data and list those like this :

```
$table_string .= "<tr><td>$attrs[ip]</td><td>$attrs[server]</td><td>$attrs[country]</td></tr>";
```

if user clicks on one of the table string he/she should be asked where the exe is and run it with attributes.

Example : "file.exe" -Connect:clicked table row ip

Sorry my english , I hope I was clear on my question any help whould be great.

Comment: Is the php running on the user's computer or what? Otherwise it makes no sense

Comment: PHP is server side, there is absolutely no way you will get it to run something "from users harddrive" - and that is a *very* good thing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all php is a server-side language. So it doesn't know anything about the client systems harddrive. You won't be able to run a client-side program with php.

However even a client-side language won't be able to do this. It is impossible for websites to run anything on the users computer and this is for good reason!!! It would be a huge security hole if you would be able to.

Comment: PHP is just a language, it's perfectly capable of doing client side applications. http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php

Comment: I guess I should have stated that I'm asuming he is using php as a server-side language

Comment: I read some articles about run exe with exec so it must be possible to run exe true php when user clicks on that link. What I wont to do is on my webpage here http://www.turkish-hunters.com/serverlist.php

Comment: there on my page you can see servers listed. I just need if user clicks one of the servers it will ask them for their game exe and run it with attribute like so : "game.exe" -Connect:clickedserver

Comment: As your php is on your webserver, it doesn't know anything about the clients system. php does indeed have exec, but you can only use it to run something on the same computer as the php script. In your case your webserver.

Comment: so how whould I go with if the exe is in C:/game.exe ?

Comment: You mean on the clients computer? You can't and for good reason. It would be a huge security risk.

Comment: huhh , with activx it works but chouldnt find out how to run with attribute.